# How to bind multiple links with same knockout function passing different IDs

Tags: javascript, html, rest, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

**Question:** I am new to **KnockoutJS**. Following example code is working for me. But you can see that **fetch** function is hard coded and working for only user with **id=100**. How can I create a **Get** link with each row in the html table list and pass **id** of that record to **fetch** function that shows record only for that particular row in console. Any Idea?

**HTML:**

```
<div  id="users-view-data">

    <button type="button" data-bind="click: fetch">Get</button>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: remove">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: listAll">Get All</button>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: collection">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text: id"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: code"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: created"></span></td>
                <td>Get Link will come here to call fetch funtion</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {

    'use strict';

    var UserViewModel = function() {
        this.service = ko.rest.service('http://domain/users');
        this.model = ko.observable( { id:0, name:'', code:'' } );
        this.collection = ko.observableArray([]);
    };

    UserViewModel.prototype.listAll = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.service.query(function(data) {
           self.collection(data);
        });
    };

    UserViewModel.prototype.fetch = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.service.load(100, function(data) {
            self.model(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
    };

    UserViewModel.prototype.remove = function() {
        var self = this;
        var code = ko.rest.get(self.model(), 'id');
        self.service.delete(code, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };

    ko.applyBindings( new UserViewModel(), document.getElementById("users-view-data") );

})();

</script>
```

**I am using following libraries:**

- knockout-3.3.0.js
- knockout.mapping-latest.js
- knockout-rest.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click handler to each row:

```
<tr data-bind="click:function(){$root.fetch(id)}">
    <td><span data-bind="text: id"></span></td>
    <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
</tr>
```

modify your fetch function to take an id:

```
UserViewModel.prototype.fetch = function(id) {
    var self = this;
    //do whatever with id
};
```

[(simplified) fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qacu61m/)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're after correctly, you need to replace `100` with a reference to the current ID, like this:

```
UserViewModel.prototype.fetch = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.service.load(self.model().id, function(data) {
        self.model(data);
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Yes. But I need to create a link in html with each record's row that call above fetch function with id of that record.

Comment: @Awan You mean for each item in `collection`?  Do you want to use the `id` of the item from `collection`, or the `id` of the `model` property on `UserViewModel`?

Comment: It is better to use model property. But my code stop working when I create a Get link with each row in html list.

Comment: @Awan Could you update your question to include where you want the link to be, it's not entirely clear what structure you're heading for here - it seems odd to have a link within the collection that will use a property from the parent object, rather than having a single link outside the collection etc

Comment: Please search `Get Link will come here` in my question.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your response. Other answer helped me in this thread. +1 already.